# Why Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phpMQTT file

Tags: php, mqtt, phpmqtt

I have faced a problem when I get data from cloudmqtt. I have downloaded project from this link [GitHub](https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT).

**subscribe.php**

In my `subscribe.php` file a function name **proc** called from `phpMQTT.php` file. This is `subscribe.php` file code

```
$topics['sensor_data'] = array("qos" => 0, "function" => "procmsg");
$mqtt->subscribe($topics, 0);
while($mqtt->proc()){       
}
$mqtt->close();
```

**phpMQTT.php**

In my `phpMQTT.php` file a function **proc** defined like below.

```
function proc( $loop = true){
    if(1){
        $sockets = array($this->socket);
        $w = $e = NULL;
        $cmd = 0;

            //$byte = fgetc($this->socket);
        if(feof($this->socket)){
            if($this->debug) echo "eof receive going to reconnect for good measure\n";
            fclose($this->socket);
            $this->connect_auto(false);
            if(count($this->topics))
                $this->subscribe($this->topics);    
        }

        $byte = $this->read(1, true);

        if(!strlen($byte)){
            if($loop){
                usleep(100000); //Fatal error shows this line
            }

        }else{ 

            $cmd = (int)(ord($byte)/16);
            if($this->debug) echo "Recevid: $cmd\n";

            $multiplier = 1; 
            $value = 0;
            do{
                $digit = ord($this->read(1));
                $value += ($digit & 127) * $multiplier; 
                $multiplier *= 128;
                }while (($digit & 128) != 0);

            if($this->debug) echo "Fetching: $value\n";

            if($value)
                $string = $this->read($value);

            if($cmd){
                switch($cmd){
                    case 3:
                        $this->message($string);
                    break;
                }

                $this->timesinceping = time();
            }
        }

        if($this->timesinceping < (time() - $this->keepalive )){
            if($this->debug) echo "not found something so ping\n";
            $this->ping();  
        }


        if($this->timesinceping<(time()-($this->keepalive*2))){
            if($this->debug) echo "not seen a package in a while, disconnecting\n";
            fclose($this->socket);
            $this->connect_auto(false);
            if(count($this->topics))
                $this->subscribe($this->topics);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If I use `set_limit_time(0);` in top of the phpMQTT.php file. Then when I brows `subscribe.php` in browser it never ends loading.

If I use `set_limit_time(60);` in top of the phpMQTT.php file. Then when I brows `subscribe.php` in browser after 60 seconds later I get some data(6 data) with this error.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpMQTT\examples\phpMQTT.php on line 275

Line 275 indicate that `usleep(100000);`.

If I use `set_limit_time(30);` in top of the phpMQTT.php file. Then when I brows `subscribe.php` in browser after 30 seconds later I get some data(3 data) with this error.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpMQTT\examples\phpMQTT.php on line 275

Where I am wrong? And how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `proc` method is designed to run "forever"

```
while($mqtt->proc()){ }
```

Because it returns always true the loop never ends.
So if you set time limit to 30s (or anything else) it will always fail after this time period (most likely in the `usleep` method because the script spends nearly all of the time there)

As mentioned in some ([github issue](https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT/issues/5)) - the subscribe should run on the server in background directly instead of beeing called via browser (so you avoid server-timeouts, browser-connection timeouts, ...)

Comment: run your script directly on the server 
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php
and in the script do whatever you want with the received data, e.g. write to a file / database, send it to somewhere else, ...